# RavenDB : A Simple Query<T>().ToList() returns 0 results

Tags: ravendb

Im using RavenDB (in server mode running @localhost:3000), and ASP.NET MVC3

I have this code segment which stopped working from build 289. It did work couple of times before, not sure if it was the update to 322 or something I did.

```
Session.Query<Post>().ToList().ForEach(Session.Delete);
```

It was deleting all Posts when I tried a while back, (I only have around 50 odd posts in my sample data, and 500 more to come in) and only changes I can see is these two occurring at Runtime

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll
```

And this log appears in the visual studio output window when the code segment (Session.Delete) above is actually running

```
Executing query '' on index 'dynamic/Posts' in 'http://localhost:3000'
Query returned 0/0 results
```

And in Raven logs, (a text file) there is nothing untoward

```
Request #   7: GET     -    46 ms - ZaszStore  - 200 - /indexes/dynamic/Posts?query=&start=0&pageSize=128&aggregation=None
```

This Query runs just fine :

```
Session.Load<Post>("MyPostId")
```

and fetches the correct Post Instance.

Why is a simple Session.Query().ToList() returning 0 results all the time? And Session.Query().Count() returns 0  always. What could cause this behavior, considering the SilverLight-UI (SL-UI) of Raven DB clearly shows that there are 50-odd posts in the DB?

The "Raven-Entity-Name" is correctly filled.

Comment: Can you try creating an explicit index and querying against that?

Comment: I just tried, Query against index works! But I don't want to go on creating all kinds of indexes, just to fetch all documents of a particular entity in my DB.

Comment: In the statistics tab are there any indexing error? Also try deleting the dynamic index and letting it start again from scratch.

Comment: Global statistics show 0 Errors, I will try deleting the dynamic index now, googling about it because I cant see the dynamic index in the indexes tab.

Comment: :-) I guess I should have made my comment about the index an answer then.
Was the dynamic query permanent? If so, you can look at the definition and see if it was unusual in anyway. Also, was it stale?

Comment: I still have this problem. Session.Query<Post>().ToList() returns 0 results Session.Query<Post>().Count() returns 0 but there are clearly 50 odd documents in sitting my DB and 500 more to come in. Session.Load<Post>("Valid ID") works though. Maybe this info is of use : I'm using the SLUG of the Post as ID, I changed the FindIDProperty convention such that my Slug field annotated with [ID] attribute in now the ID of the document.

Comment: using 1.0.0.322 build. SL-UI is cool :) GJ RavenTeam

Comment: Have you tried adding "WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()" to the query as @bennage suggested?

Comment: @Matt I wrote all my queries with that call included. I'm using build 287

Comment: Update, I switched to MS SQL Server, and Lucene.Net itself directly. Lucene.Net feels good (though it was nearly closed recently and now back in action, meaner and badder than ever)

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of query you can get all the docs like so:

```
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.StartsWith("post", <page>, <size>)
```

That should be easier and more efficient than issuing a query to return all the docs as it pulls them directly from the datastore, bypassing the Lucene indexes.

However it only works when you want to get all the docs that have the save prefix as their Id.

Comment: I can fetch all the docs in the database as you say, or I can fetch it using LuceneQuery feature or I can use the HTTP interface and create a web request again with a lucene query to get it. But I'm wondering why in the world the Linq provider is not working :( It is the highlight of raven db